# Error on load Model Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, sapui5

when i call my XMLModel and try to oModel.getXML a problem appears on browser console :

"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'"

But if, i oModel.setXML directly in code like:

```
oModel.setXML("<questionnaire><question><id>A01</id><text>Whats is you ID Number?</text><answer>1234</answer></question></questionnaire>");
```

then the error doesn't happen

Here is my onInit controller function :

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
    oModel.loadData("model/questionario.xml");
    var view = this.getView();  
    view.setModel(oModel);
    var oData = oModel.getXML();
    console.log(oData);

    //This is what i expect to do with the return

        var oData = oModel.getProperty("/pergunta/texto");
        var label_01 = view.byId("lbl_01");
        label_01.setText(oData);



},
```

And this is my xml Model

```
<questionnaire>
    <question>
       <id>A01</id>
       <text>Whats is you ID Number?</text>
       <answer>1234</answer>
    </question>
</questionnaire>
```

Thanks for all helps

Comment: Your model is missing a closing `</questionario>` tag

Comment: Probably Qualiture is right. But just in case and since my limited spanish does not give me much context: Data returned to a XMLModel is only allowed to have one root node.

Comment: Sorry, the </questionario> its there, i just forget in here when i paste the code in the question

Comment: This is one xml in english, for example with the same structure <questionnaire>
<question>
    <id>A01</id>
    <text>Whats is you ID Number?</texto>
    <resposta>1234</resposta>
</question>
</questionnaire>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably suffering from the asynchronous nature of the data loading; you are trying to get the data while the data is not yet loaded.

Either switch to synchronous load -- *definitely not recommended!* -- or get the data once the data is loaded using the `attachRequestCompleted` event handler:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
oModel.loadData("model/questionario.xml");

oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent) {
    var oData = oModel.getXML();
    console.log(oData);
});
```